# Convert UTF-16 unicode characters to UTF-8 in java

Tags: java, json, unicode, utf-8

When I got JSON then there are \u003c and \u003e instead of < and >. I want to convert them back to utf-8 in java. any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 3c and 3e *are* `<` and `>`.  What do you need to convert anything for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Strings to and from UTF8 byte arrays in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java)

Comment: What JSON parser are you using?

Comment: Indeed, the correct way to decode JSON string literals is to use a JSON parser. Do not attempt to decode escape sequences yourself because you probably won't get it exactly right. A JSON parser will give you a standard Unicode String object; if you really need to convert that into UTF-8-encoded bytes you can use `getBytes`, but I'm not sure that's really relevant.

Comment: If you using a `StringEntitiy` you should take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6228377/356895).

Answer (score 14):

```
try {
    // Convert from Unicode to UTF-8
    String string = "\u003c";
    byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // Convert from UTF-8 to Unicode
    string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
}
```

refer http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/unicodetoutf8.html

Comment: I have used this technique also but it is not working. It returns same string which I passes... although it works in test application. Below is what I am using.



    public static String unicodeToUTF8(String unicodeStr) 
  {
       // Convert from Unicode to UTF-8
       byte[] utf8 = unicodeStr.getBytes("UTF-8");
       String UTF8Str="";
       UTF8Str = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
       return UTF8Str;
  }

Comment: it works in test application means there is some problem in application code please check twise the function `unicodeToUTF8`in your application

Comment: I have checked this lots of time and on both test and live applications file.encoding is same i.e. cp1252. What would be the possible options?

Comment: The reason a test application with `String string = "\u003c"` works is because `\u003c` is a compiler escape just like '\n' is a compiler escape. If you want to test JSON input you have to add an additional level of escaping: `String string = "\\u003c";` And in order to process these you need a library that handles these escapes for you. Your JSON parser should be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try converting the string into a byte array

```
byte[] utfString = str.getBytes("UTF-8") ;
```

and convert that back to a string object by specifying the UTF-8 encoding like

```
str = new String(utfString,"UTF-8") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
String s = "Hello World!";
String convertedInUTF8 = new String(s, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```