# How to convert(unescape) string to char, for example "\\n" to '\n', in java

Tags: java, escaping

I'm working on reading some utf-16 and ascii mixed files such as:
\u6b64\u626b\u63cf: abc

And I will get "\\u6b64\\u626b\\u63cf: abc"(string length is 29) in java. 
How can I convert it into "\u6b64\u626b\u63cf: abc"(string length is 8)?

I know there is StringEscapeUtils in Apache Commons library, but I prefer not to use outer libraries.

Or, is it possible that I can read it directly to "\u6b64\u626b\u63cf: abc"?

Comment: I think this is answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075603/convert-utf-16-unicode-characters-to-utf-8-in-java

Comment: But I got something like "\\u6b64", not "\u6b64".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not to have a general lib to use.
But I found this private method in the Properties class of java, which totally solves my problem.

> ```
> private String loadConvert (char[] in, int off, int len, char[] convtBuf) {
>     if (convtBuf.length < len) {
>         int newLen = len * 2;
>         if (newLen < 0) {
>             newLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
>         }
>         convtBuf = new char[newLen];
>     }
>     char aChar;
>     char[] out = convtBuf;
>     int outLen = 0;
>     int end = off + len;
>     while (off < end) {
>         aChar = in[off++];
>         if (aChar == '\\') {
>             aChar = in[off++];
>             if(aChar == 'u') {
>                 // Read the xxxx
>                 int value=0;
>                 for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
>                     aChar = in[off++];
>                     switch (aChar) {
>                       case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
>                       case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
>                          value = (value << 4) + aChar - '0';
>                          break;
>                       case 'a': case 'b': case 'c':
>                       case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':
>                          value = (value << 4) + 10 + aChar - 'a';
>                          break;
>                       case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':
>                       case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
>                          value = (value << 4) + 10 + aChar - 'A';
>                          break;
>                       default:
>                           throw new IllegalArgumentException(
>                                        "Malformed \\uxxxx encoding.");
>                     }
>                  }
>                 out[outLen++] = (char)value;
>             } else {
>                 if (aChar == 't') aChar = '\t';
>                 else if (aChar == 'r') aChar = '\r';
>                 else if (aChar == 'n') aChar = '\n';
>                 else if (aChar == 'f') aChar = '\f';
>                 out[outLen++] = aChar;
>             }
>         } else {
>             out[outLen++] = aChar;
>         }
>     }
>     return new String (out, 0, outLen);
> }
> ```