# gson serialization of unicode string not working

Tags: java, android, unicode, utf-8, gson

I am using gson library to serialize my data into a json format string. When I receive the json message on the server I get a question mark for unicode characters. For example, I send the following from my android client:

```
{"message_content":"This is a test message: مرحبا أصدقاء"}
```

But the server receives it as:

```
{"message_content":"This is a test message: ???? ??????"}
```

**Code:**

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class TestMessage {

    @SerializedName("message_content")
    private String mMessageContent;

    public TestMessage(String messageContent) {

        try {
            byte[] utf8 = messageContent.getBytes("UTF-8");
            mMessageContent = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            mMessageContent = messageContent;
        }
    }

    public String toJSON() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like your problem in server side, are you using php or asp?

Comment: @JafarKhQ thanks for your reply, problem seems to be in the way I used HTTP post. I had to explicitly setEntity to support unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I debugged and found that the HTTP post didn't support UTF-8. Followed this post: [Android default charset when sending http post/put - Problems with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227747/android-default-charset-when-sending-http-post-put-problems-with-special-chara)

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, HTTP.UTF_8));
```