# How to use UTF-8 encoding in Android?

Tags: android, utf-8, xml-parsing

I am working on an French Android App, where the Accents like é, ê, â, etc.... are displaying like Symbols, which is fetched for an XML Link. How do I fix this to display the Characters in French assents?

Comment: have look at this URL it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270591/post-utf-8-encoded-data-to-server-loses-certain-characters

Answer (score 0):

Read UTF-8 XML file in Java – (SAX Parser)

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

[Post UTF-8 encoded data to server loses certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270591/post-utf-8-encoded-data-to-server-loses-certain-characters)