# How to encode russian text in Post request using Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, httpclient

There is the following Java code:

```
    public static void register(UserInfo info) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException, RegistrationException {
        List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", info.getName()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", info.getEmail()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", info.getPassword()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("genus", String.valueOf(info.getGenus())));
        String response=doPostRequest(params, REGISTRATION_URL);
    }

private static String doPostRequest(List<NameValuePair> params, String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 

    return getContentFromInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
} 

private static String getContentFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

As you can see above, I send POST request and get response. But in register method I use russian name (cyrillic), and there is "????? ???" on my server. How can I fix it? How can I encode russian text?

Comment: What do you pass as your content-type? What charset?

Comment: Which server are you using?

Answer (score 11):

You need to set your request encoding to UTF-8.

```
The request or response body can be any encoding, but by default is ISO-8859-1. The encoding may be specified in the Content-Type header, for example:
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

From: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/charencodings.html

An example of how this is accomplished:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");
```

Additionally, I see your using `UrlEncodedFormEntity`. 
You should add encoding to the constructor as so:

```
new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270591/post-utf-8-encoded-data-to-server-loses-certain-characters . Also, make sure your reading UTF-8 also on the server.

Answer (score 3):

you should try encoding parameters

```
URLEncoder.encode(URL, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are reading or writing the response wrong?

Make sure you use the same encoding in both **writing the request** and **reading it** and in the **post http headers**.

To define encoding for read data use [InputStreamReader(InputStream, Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

httpclient.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, "UTF-8");

Comment: Please explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you tired of searching for correct headers / encoding combinations, you can encode string to URI format and decode back, this will preserve any non-ascii chars

```
String cyrillicString = "ыыыыыы";

//encode string into URI format
String transportString = URLEncoder.encode(cyrillicString, "UTF-8");

//transport string somewhere 

//decode back
String decodedString = URLDecoder.decode(transportString, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you post as json:

1. Create client

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
//add header with charset UTF-8
clientBuilder.setDefaultHeaders(Arrays.asList(new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType()))); //application/json;charset=UTF-8
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
```

2. Create HttpPost

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("/hostIp:port/forexample/saveMyObject");
```

3. Write object as string (String)

```
PostRequestExample request = new PostRequestExample();
request.setUsername("userName");
request.setUserAge(98));

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); //import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
//ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON - encode russian symbols as UTF8
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

4. execute

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```