# How to send Emoji Icons on php server with Multipart Entity

Tags: android, emoji, multipartentity

I am working on a project in which I am using this library https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon. I am able to see the Emoji Keyboard but when I am sending the text from Editext which contains Emoji Icons they are converted into ??

After some research I found out this solution [Post UTF-8 encoded data to server loses certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270591/post-utf-8-encoded-data-to-server-loses-certain-characters)

By using this

```
form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8");
```

the problem get solved. But I have to use MultipartEntity to send images also to server.

When I set Encoding in MultiPartEntity like below:

```
MultiPartEntity entity = new MultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,
                        null, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), new MultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                            }
                        });
```

It is not working here, how can achieve the same with MultipartEntity. Please help me.

Comment: If you are storing the message in database on your server then you can use 'utf8mb4_general_ci' collation for the message field

Comment: Also on php side while working with database you need to add mysqli_query($dbh,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
 mysqli_query($dbh,"SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_general_ci'"); while making connection with database

Comment: Doing so does not changing anything, I am still getting the same issue. Please help me if you have any idea how to solve it as it is working fine with 
UrlEncodedFormEntity. 
Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by doing the below change:

MultiPartEntity entity = new MultiPartEntity(new MultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                            }
                        });

entity.addPart("body", new StringBody(mStatusBodyField.getText().toString(),
                        Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

Added Char set to the body that contains Emojis before sending it to server.

Comment: Please use the method provided by @PrithnirajNicyone .. i.e. entity.addPart("body", new StringBody(mStatusBodyField.getText().toString(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); Thank you so much